How to Update multiple widgets without triggering a Changed signal
What would be the appropriate way to update binded-fields without triggering a chain of Changed events?
Considering the following scenario:

Changing StartDate should update Months
Changing EndDate should update Months and ExtraMonths
Changing ExtraDate should update ExtraMonths
Changing Months should update EndDate and ExtraMonths
Changing ExtraMonths should update ExtraDate
The problem is that if for example I edit the EndDate box, it triggers 3 cascading events, which isn't really necessary.
So right now, I do it like this:
def end_date_changed(self, new_end_date):
        self.spinBox_months.blockSignals(True)   # disable raising a signal
        self.spinBox_months.setValue(Months)     # update Months spinbox without updating EndDate and ExtraMonths
        self.spinBox_months.blockSignals(False)  # re-enable raising signals

        self.spinBox_extra_months.blockSignals(True)
        self.spinBox_extra_months.setValue(Extra_Months)  # update ExtraMonths spinbox without updating ExtraDate
        self.spinBox_extra_months.blockSignals(False)

And the same for plenty others like them.
It seems to me like a bad way of doing it. Is there a better way?

It is not a bad way. The method blockSignals exists for exactly this purpose. GUI code always has a seemingly huge amount of boilerplate if you compare it to logic code.

only change which could be made is to not blindly return to accepting signals, but to rather get the prior signal blocking status (the return value of the first call to blockSignals), and after setting the value, restore the old value rather than simply False. This is likely not relevant however in most simple use-cases. There are also instances where it isn't necessary to block the signals at all, as the cascaded signal back to the origin will call setValue to the same value, so there will be no change, and the signal loop will be broken. Be careful with trying that though...

In situations like these, where multiple objects have complex relations between themselves but they are all correlated at some level, it's sometimes better to connect all "value changed" signals to a single function, get the sender() that originates it (and, therefore, its new value) and finally update all widgets using QSignalBlocker, except the one that changed in the first place.

@musicamante, That sound like a proper solution, thanks. I'll check it out
